# App stop working when Image Picker is opened in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am developing a React Native application using React Native. I am using react native image picker library, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-imagepicker to pick up the images from the Gallery. But when I opened the image picker, my app stopped working and exited.

This is my code

```
import React from "react";
import { CameraRoll, View, Text, Button, Alert, Image } from "react-native";
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker";

// More info on all the options is below in the API Reference... just some common use cases shown here
const options = {
  title: "Select Avatar",
  customButtons: [{ name: "fb", title: "Choose Photo from Facebook" }],
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: "images"
  }
};

class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      url:"https://www.designevo.com/res/templates/thumb_small/terrible-black-bat-icon.png",
      avatarSource: null
    };
  }

  saveToCameraRoll = () => {
    let { url } = this.state;
  };

  _handlePickImageButton = () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      console.log("Response = ", response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        Alert.alert("User cancelled image picker")
      } else if (response.error) {
        //console.log("ImagePicker Error: ", response.error);
        Alert.alert("ImagePicker Error:");
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        //console.log("User tapped custom button: ", response.customButton);
        Alert.alert("Custom button");
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri };
        // You can also display the image using data:
        // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

        this.setState({
          avatarSource: source
        });
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            this._handlePickImageButton();
          }}
          title="Pick a image"
        >
          Pick image
        </Button>
        <Image source={this.state.avatarSource} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Gallery;
```

What is wrong with my code? Also, I did not get any error info in the console as in the screenshot attached below.

[image]

I tried, opening in this way too

```
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      //nothing implemented yet
    });
```

It just stopped working.

I added the following permission in the plist as well:

[image]

I tried this too

```
const options = {
      noData: true
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {

    });
```

Comment: are you sure do you use it properly? from documentation, I see that there are only I API method you can call from `ImagePicker` - it is `open`

Comment: Hi, the custom button feature is working

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. The problem was in the plist. When I was adding the permissions, I just copy-pasted from a post. Might be something was wrong with it. When I typed in the permissions in the XCode, I saw the suggestion box, so I just clicked on the suggestion box and added the description for each permission as below.

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, the String value in the Type column is grayed out and cannot be changed. In the screenshot attached in the question, those values can be changed. That is the difference.